# Counting using for loops in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to count the number of times `'fizz'` appears in a list.

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in x:
        if item=='fizz':
             count +=1
        return count
```

This python program returns:

`"Oops, try again. fizz_count(['buzz', 'buzz', 'fizz', 'buzz']) returned 0 instead of the correct answer: 1"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please check out the faq on how to ask a proper question before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Move your `return count` back out a tab.

Comment: There are forums on Codecademy which usually address common issues with the exercises.  In the bottom left corner, click "Q&A Forum"

Comment: this question is legit.  It's easy to get caught on Python indentation syntax if you're new.  And the level of meaning ascribed to indentation makes Python different from many other languages.

Comment: thanx a lot for helping me to improve, seriously I'm new to stackoverflow as well as python

Answer (score 4):

You are returning after the first iteration, you need to loop over all the elements, then return outside the loop:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in x:
        if item=='fizz':
             count +=1
    return count # outside the loop
```

The first element in x is `"buzz"`, you are returning inside the loop so you only check that first element and return count which is `0`, moving  the return outside the loop means you check every element in `x`.

Your code can be simplified to a returning a generator expression using [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def fizz_count(x):
   return sum(s == "fizz" for s in x)
```

Comment: thanx a lot, I only knew some java before started learning python ,so I couldn't recognize the whitespace problem

Answer (score 2):

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count=0
    for item in x:
        if item=='fizz':
             count +=1
    return count
```

In your code function return result in first for iteration where count = 0

Comment: thanx a lot, I only knew some java before started learning python ,so I couldn't recognize the whitespace problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

```
return count
```

is breaking out of fizzCount after the first iteration of the loop, when only the first "buzz" was value-checked.  Thus, count did not have a chance to increment.

Python is a bit different from other languages - it uses indentation level where other languages might use brackets, do/end or other non-whitespace characters to represent the scope of methods and blocks.  This can be a bit confusing for newcomers, and it looks like this is where you were caught.

Unindent `return count` by 1 tab so it is called after the loop ends.

Comment: thanx a lot, I only knew some java before started learning python ,so I couldn't recognize the whitespace problem